# Android apps without public ip address

Tags: android, rest, ip

I am working on a system where an android app registers itself to a HTTP server (REST) in order to be notified of events.

The problem in real time is that the mobile phone doesn't have a **public IP address**.

This public IP address is usually needed by the server in order to communicate with the mobile app.

How can we resolve this problem, enabling mobile phones that do not have public IPs' to be notified by the server?

N.B : the application is for assigning missions to an agent, so we need to send, say an object conatingin the mission description, the place etc...

Comment: This is what push notifications are for. Try looking at [GCM] (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: @shyam : I am sending Objects to the android. In fact the application is for assigning missions to an agent, so we need to send say an object conatingin the mission description, the place etc... CGM still works for this? thanks

Comment: You can send complex objects as JSONs.

Comment: @shyam :   
Does this make us Google dependant?

Comment: @shyam : is GCM the unique solution ?

Comment: There are plenty of push notification services available. GCM is just the most widely used one.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could keep the connection to the server and do a push from the server with the informations to the Client through the Connection.
2. Use the Google Cloud Messaging instead

Comment: Does this make us Google dependant?

Comment: Kind of yes, that was my (1) suggestion. But you have more work to make it stable.